# Regular Expression Notepad++ to Find & replace strings

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

I have strings like following in a line

Q80a_Offline_MElDor_NET
Q80a_Offline_Mr_NET
Q80a_Offline_Mor_NET

I want to remove **_NET** from them using regex in Notepad++.

I also have following in the same line in the file which I don't want to touch.

Q80a_MElDor_NET
Q80a_Mr_NET
Q80a_Mor_NET

I can find these strings with following search string.

**^Q80a_offline_[a-zA-Z]+_NET$**

but not sure what to use as replace with regex expression

I want **Q80a_Offline_MElDor_NET** to be **Q80a_Offline_MElDor**

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_NET$
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/55

or

```
^(Q80a_offline_[a-zA-Z]+)_NET$
```

Replace by `$1`.

Comment: I vks, thanks for your reply and it works. But I have some similar words which I don't want to touch somewhere in the same line. I have updated my question.

Comment: @Pak try the regex after `or`.the `2nd` regex